# Ember nested routing with pods

Tags: ember.js

i have 2 routes trains, teams created with pods.

```
trains
  --route.js
  --template.hbs

teams
  --route.js
  --template.hbs
```

**Router**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('trains', function(){
    this.route('teams', {path: '/:train_name'});
  });
});
```

When i navigate to /trains/some-train-name/teams. it did not invoke teams route. it is looking for a template 'trains/teams'. is it expecting my teams folder to be inside trains folder. how to nest these 2 separate routes

Answer (score 1):

```
trains
  --route.js // common for all subroutes
  --template.hbs // common for all subtemplates
  index
    --route.js
    --template.hbs
  teams
    --route.js
    --template.hbs
```

try next structure

If you still need to keep structure you show -- you need to update your Resolver
`app/resolver.js`

```
export default Ember.Resolver.extend({
    resolve(fullName) {
       // put custom logic here
    }
});
```

I can't give you certain code, cause I need to debug to make it works
Read more at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html

P.S.

did you try ?

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('trains');
  this.route('teams', {path: 'trains/:train_name/teams'});
});
```

Comment: Do you want me to put teams folder inside trains folder. If so i dont want that. i want to put trains and teams content separately as shown in the figure

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri did you try just another structure of routes? as in PS in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [reset the namespace](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resetting-nested-route-namespace) so both routes are actually top-level, instead of `teams` beings namespaced inside `trains`. I do **not** recommend this, as it makes the structure confusing:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('trains', function(){
    this.route('teams', { path: '/:train_name', resetNamespace: true });
  });
});
```